# Calling web services from an ASP.Net application authenticated with WIF

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, authentication, wif

I have a ASP.Net web application which authenticates using passive authentication with a WIF STS. I want to host web services on this STS to access it's membership and related data.

How would the ASP.Net application authenticate with the web services? Is this active federation? At the moment the services will be on the same application as the ID / STS but it would be nice if these could be split off in the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first question would be: what are you accessing the service for? Create users? delete users? change claims to be issued? Get more information about a specific user?

Are these operations going to be executed by all users (like in "self service" use cases)? only by some (e.g. admins)?

You *could* use claims to protect this service. In that case, if the ASP.NET app calls the membership/related data service on behalf the original user, then you would need to get an "ActAs" token (from the same STS).

You could also opt for a "trusted subsystem" approach where the site calls the service with its own identity. In that case you can use claims (no "ActAs" necessary) or some other authentication (like an API key).

It also depends on how the service is implemented (as in REST, SOAP, etc). SOAP would require implementing WS-Trust (using WIF or WCF), REST would require using something else.

Comment: Thank you Eugenio, yes creating / editing and getting additional information. Self serve + Admins. Services will be SOAP. Many thanks for the detailed answer, I have already started on the ActAs solution, some users will have Admin roles which I hope will be passed through in the ActAs token. Max